# restrict with pointers that don't alias at function call but do afterwards

Tags: c, restrict-qualifier

Is this safe?

foo.h:

```
struct A {
        struct B *b;
        // more fields
};
struct B {
        // some fields
};

void foo(struct A *restrict a, struct B *restrict b);
```

foo.c:

```
void foo(struct A *restrict a, struct B *restrict b)
{
        a->b = &b;
}
```

bar.c:

```
void bar(void)
{
        struct A a;
        struct B b;

        // some code. a and b are independent here.
        foo(&a, &b);
        // some more code.  Now a and b aren't independent anymore.
}
```

I wonder if the compiler may incorrectly assume from the function declaration that `a` can't be used to access `b` after `foo(&a, &b);` and therefore may optimize things that shouldn't.

Comment: Now I think this is wrong.  A function shouldn't be declared to be restrict in this case.